# how to fixed task.getresult().getdownloadurl()

Tags: java, android

I need your help. I have a error.

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(username) && imageUri !=null)
                {
                    if (ischeck)
                    {
                        StorageReference userimage = storageReference.child("profile_images").child(userid+".jpg");
                        userimage.putFile(imageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                                if(task.isSuccessful())
                                {
                                    final Uri download_uri;
                                    if (task !=null)
                                    {
                                        download_uri = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl();
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: *"I have a error."* - Please tell us what the error is.  Is it a compilation error?   A runtime error?  Is here a stacktrace?  Is there anything else that you could help us help you?

Answer (score 0):

Without details on what runtime/compile errors you get, I can only speculate and check for typos.

> StorageReference userimage =
>   storageReference.child("profile_images").child(userid+".jpg");

Should "storageReference.child" start with a small s, instead of a large S? After checking [this page](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference&method=child), I wonder if the problem is in just the block of code you've shared with us, and not some larger context like the method it's in.